# mysqldump_wrokbench data export advanced options not full and all mysqldump option support

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, dump, workbench

It's no full support and not flexible(WORKBENCH), still no solution....

I want to create dump scripts of each table in my database....
workbench 5.2.47 CE version i am using... 
I checked 
My database and all tables
And options like  dump stored routines, dump events

in advanced options i checked.......

```
add-locks,
complete-insert, 
replace,
hex-blob,
disable-keys,
order-by-primary,
create-options, 
allow-keywords,
quote-names
```

Problems.

1. How I save the configuration setting or all above setting I did..and second time I want to add just my setting file if I save.. And create a dump
2. CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `mydatabase` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
   USE `mydatabase`;

   ..................This one I want to skip or exclude form dump scripts but there are no options in workbench as in mysql command is there `--no-create-db, -n` and for remove USE `mydatabase` remove option as `--databases`

All mysqldump options are not available which I need.............

Any solution for above questions or any custom create options in workbench...
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just met similar problems and found the following way to add options.
My environment is:

- Windows 8/64bit
- MySQL Workbench 6.08
  (you may adjust the step according to your system such as Linux)

First, close MySQL Workbench

In the folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.0.8\modules
there are many python files, there is a file called

1. **wb_admin_export_options.py** which is Python source code and  there is
   another file with same name
2. **wb_admin_export_options.pyc** which is a compiled Python file.

**Step to Edit**

rename 2 into wb_admin_export_options.pyc-org to avoid the program
read the old option list and make a copy of 1 in case there is any
    problem

run your code editor in Administrator mode if in Window for UAC reason.
Open wb_admin_export_options.py

Note: You will see the option list for mysqldump which is appear in 
Workbench->Administration[Tab]->Advanced Options...[button on the top right]

**Note on editing the file**

Add the option you need in the list similar to the source code, eg:
The true of false near the closing bracket means default value (check or uncheck by default)

"create-options":["Include all MySQL-specific table options in CREATE TABLE statements.","TRUE"],

Open the MySQL Workbench again and it will read the updated option list and let you choose from.

Hope this help.

Comment: @Prasad if you find it to be the solution, would you mind to accept the answer? Many thanks.

Comment: tried this with workbench 6.3 to add `"default-character-set":["utf8mb4 is where it's at.","utf8mb4","STR"]`   get a 'local variable "default" referenced before assignment' error  ☹