# mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'delayed-insert=FALSE'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to export data from mydatabase which is in MySQL Workbench 6.3.CE on Windows 10, to to export my data and I encountered the following error.
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'delayed-insert=FALSE'  Operation failed with exitcode 7"  in mysql workbench.
Any one who know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the "wb_admin_export_options.py" file in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.3.CE\modules as per: 
[mysqldump_wrokbench data export advanced options not full and all mysqldump option support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760732/mysqldump-wrokbench-data-export-advanced-options-not-full-and-all-mysqldump-opti)

Thanks StackOverflow